# Replace every item in that index and write to file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a normal list, and I want to change the element of that list every 25 indexes (starting by the second index). So I've created a loop to generate that number and store it in a list (i.e 2,27,52,77....). Then I've printed every item of that index, but for now I can't seem to find a way to work with re.sub.
I want to replace those elements by new ones, and then write all of items on the list (not just those I've changed) into a file.

**So the goal is using re.sub or some other method to replace:**

```
'  Title                  =' by '  Author                 ='
```

How do I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
counter = 0           
length = len(flist) # Max.Size of List
ab = [2] 

for item in flist:
    counter +=1    
    a = ((25*counter)+2) #Increment 
    ab.append(a)
    if a >= length:
        ab.pop() #Removing last item
        break

for i in ab: 
    print(flist[i-1]) #Printing element in that index
    #replace item

#write to file
fo = open('somefile.txt', 'w')
for item in flist:    
 fo.write(item)

fo.close()
```

**PS: I'm new to python, sugestions and criticism is much apreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

To match the text you can use:

```
new_str = re.sub(r'\s+Title\s+=', 'Author                 =', old_str)
```

`\s` means whitespace, `+` means one or more. You can use `\s{4}` to match exactly 4 whitespaces, or as many as you need. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Alternatively, you can use `replace()`:

```
new_str = old_str.replace('  Title                  =', 'Author                 =')
```

---

You can use `range()` to simplify the rest of your code a bit. range() has 3 arguments, 2 of which are optional; start, end, step.

```
for i in range(2, 200, 25):
    print(i)
```

Finally, you can use `with open()` instead of `open()`:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as fo:
    # Do stuff here.
    ....
    ....
    # File closes automatically.
```

Comment: How do I replace the previous item with the one we've created now?

Comment: `re.sub()` creates a new string. I edited the code to make it clear. You simple use `new_str`.

Comment: Both method's work like a charm :D My question is, after we replace it, how do we remove the older one and write that new one in the same place? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: `re.sub()` checks a string, and always returns a new string after replacing the match (if it exists). It doesn't modify the old string. Strings are immutable. For example for second element you can simply use `my_list[1] = re.sub(str1, str2 , my_list[1])`, where str1 is what you are looking for, and str2 what you replace it with. Check more about immutables here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for i in ab:
    fixed = re.sub("/  Title                  =/", "  Author                 =", flist[i-1])
    print(fixed) #Printing replaced line
```

Disclaimer: I'm on a mobile device so can't test for correctness